# How to resolve error with drupal commerce 2 installation via composer

Tags: commerce, composer

I am following the instructions at http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/getting-started/install.html

After providing the  console command for a new installation, console starts to download the various requirements, but before completion, returns the following error.

> Failed to execute git checkout '879356bbf75608f86d8fb89d76a21dc1e99a39ae' -- && git reset --hard '879356bbf75608f86d8fb89d76a21dc1e99a39ae' --
>     fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I have read elsewhere that I need to initialise a git repo first? Not sure if I am missing something or whether the documentation is incomplete. I assumed it was a one line command.

What am I doing wrong and how do I resolve this?

I am not a very advanced user and intend to use Acquia Dev Desktop as working environment.

Further to the above, I went on to try creating the MYSITE directory first and then ran git init from within this folder. I then ran the composer commands for a full install, and then received another error as below.

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Project directory commerce8/ is not empty.

Comment: You shouldn't need any additional steps, looks like a temporary failure. Delete the commerce8 folder and try again.

Comment: Thank Bojan, but still finding the same problem though. The following url appears to describe the problem, but the suggested fix does not work for me. http://webadio.com/how-to-fix-the-failed-to-execute-git-checkout-exception-when-running-composer-update-with-symfony-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem of running composer through Acquia Dev Desktop's terminal launcher.

When using native terminal the installation completes without issue.